# How to change the position of every second wordpress post using nth-child?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

Heeey friends,

I'm trying to do this, I want to change positions of every second post, from left to right.

Here is an example:

[image]

I used for the "main-content" the nth-child(even) and it works fine, but for the other div its just doesn't work at all.

**CSS:**

```
.archive-cc {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 80;
    background-color: floralwhite;
    border-bottom: pink 10px solid;
}

.archive-content {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.archive-cc:nth-child(even)>div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 50;
}

.meta {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
}

.meta-text {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.meta:nth-child(even)>div {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="archive-cc">
  <div class="meta">
    <div class="meta-text">PLS WOOOORK</div>
  </div>
  <div class="archive-content">
    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="test">test</a>test</h2>
    <div class="entry-summary">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I literally tried everything already, I hope someone can help me! It looks like this right now: http://helga-fruehauf-koehler.de/wordpress/fotografie/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to use any floating layout here, but [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to reach your goal. This is supported by modern browsers and easier to work with.

1. Found a very good resource on [how to split flexbox items into multiple rows at tobiasahlin's blog](https://tobiasahlin.com/blog/flexbox-break-to-new-row/).
2. Found a very good explanation on [flex-direction on css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-direction/). This also includes an Codepen example using different CSS classes per flex-direction.

Here is my solution using the [nth-child pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) which abstracts away the `.row` and `.row-reverse` CSS classes from example above.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vp8xbqus/1/

Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
</ul>
  
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
</ul>

<!-- add more boxes as above -->

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px;
}

.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

// Abstraction for .row and .row-reverse styles based on nth-child

.wrapper :nth-child(odd) {
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper :nth-child(odd) :first-child {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper :nth-child(even) { 
  -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse; 
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.wrapper :nth-child(even) :first-child {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  background: gold;
}
```